# How to remove all options from a multiselect dropdown?

Tags: jquery, frontend, dropdown

I want to remove all options from a multiselect dropdown list.

```
<select id='pre-selected-options' multiple='multiple'>
    <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
    <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
    <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
    <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
</select>
```

$('#pre-selected-options').multiSelect();

I wanna remove all options in #pre-selected-options. How can I do it?

Comment: Use the api methods of the plugin. After reviewing the documentation - show us what you tried that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pre-selected-options').empty();
$('#pre-selected-options').multiselect("rebuild");
```

First line of the code will remove the option from the element. And the second line update the multiselect element.

Comment: While you answer might solve the problem, you should always leave a note to the answer about why your answer would solve the problem, so others can learn from it.

Comment: Thank you but, Your answer didn't solve the problem nothing actually occurred.

Comment: did you check the console

Comment: "[Violation] 'input' handler took 651ms"
"[Violation] 'change' handler took 932ms" This what showed up in the console

Comment: http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods use 
.multiselect('rebuild') see edited answer